# Creating a single python module out of several different modules

Tags: python, object, module, python-import

We have several different modules that we are trying to keep in separate files/modules for organizational purposes as if we consolidated them all into a single file it would create a monster file that would be hard to navigate. However we want to be able to import them into a single module where we can call all the associated functions so it is easy to use in our scripts.

As an example of what we are trying to accomplish.

We have n number of files that are in the structure:

```
# module1.py
class Module1():
     def __init__(self, file):
         self.file = load.file

     def get_item_from_file():
        return self.file['path']['to']['item']
```

We would like to have a single file that has

```
# all_modules.py
from module1 import Module1
from moduleN import ModuleN 

class AllModules():
      def __init__(self,file):
          self.file = load.file
          # Some magic to instantiate all the functions in Module1-N
          # so they can be instantiated by making an AllModules object
```

In other words we want to be able to use the above module as follows

```
#Somescript.py
from all_modules import AllModules
file = some_file_input
test = AllModules(file)
item_in_file = test.get_item_from_file()
```

Any advice would be appreciated, as we are pretty new to this type of module work. We want to make sure we are doing it a pythonic way versus just hacking something together.

Comment: It looks like you're coming from Java. Classes and modules are completely different things, and it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: I am not coming from Java, however my terminology could be off. We could in theory have several classes per module1.py file. I just was trying to keep the example simple. That being said if the problem is solved by changing our structures, I would be interested

Comment: Why is everything in a class? Why are you trying to make a class just to combine a bunch of functions from a bunch of other classes? I get the feeling you're going to wind up with some awful multiple-inheritance monstrosity for something that shouldn't be defining any classes at all. It looks like you should be writing module-level functions.

Comment: We had come from an object model with backwards inheritance, we were trying to keep the objects but remove the complicated inheritance tree. You might be right that treating it as module level functions could fix our problems.

Comment: @user2357112 one question though, I would see how we could then easily import the functions into a file. But would we be able to link them to our main object AllModules so we could instantiate an instance of it to use in our script?

Comment: Why does your AllModules class need to exist? It doesn't seem to be modeling any useful concept.

Comment: We need it because we need a single object that we can instantiate in our scripts that will give us access to all of the functions

Comment: Sounds like you should be using the module object for that (the thing `all_modules` resolves to after `import all_modules`) and pass the file as an argument to the functions instead of as state on the object. That, or maybe make deeper design changes.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't care that you're not doing "from moduleX import ModuleX" statements, you can do string based imports.

```
import importlib

def my_import(name):
    components = name.split('.')
    mod = __import__(components[0])
    for comp in components[1:]:
       mod = getattr(mod, comp)
    return mod

imports = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for f in files:
        if f.startswith("module"):
            # find module number magic.
            imports.apppend(my_import(f.replace('.py', '') + ".module" + str(modulenumber))
```

Then, reference the module by

```
class_instance = imports[i]()
```

This code isn't exactly fully tested, but the documented way of importing specific classes by string in dynamic files.